# ActiveRecord "where" produces different object than "pluck"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord, lazy-loading, where-clause

I need to eliminate a step in this process.

I first use "where" to find the profile with a matching id

```
@facebook_profile = FacebookProfile.where(:facebook_id => session[:facebook_profile_id])
```

That produces an object that look like this (Note the surrounding square brackets)

```
[#<FacebookProfile id: 94, etc.]
```

If I do:

```
$ @facebook_profile.id
```

The result is

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f919cb0b3c0>>
```

Then I'm using pluck to produce a different object, but this requires that I use the previous relation, @facebook_profile.

```
@new_facebook_profile = FacebookProfile.find_by_my_column(@facebook_profile.pluck(:my_column))
```

That produces a relation WITHOUT square brackets:

```
#<FacebookProfile id: 94, etc.>
```

On this object, I can call:

```
@new_facebook_profile.id
```

and get my correct result

How can I do @facebook_profile.id and get the correct result instead of an error? I suspect this has something to do with lazy loading, but I can't be sure. I know it has something to do with the brackets around the relation. I would like to get rid of the "pluck" step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
@facebook_profile = FacebookProfile.where(:facebook_id => session[:facebook_profile_id]).first
```

Then you can use `@facebook_profile.id` directly.

The `#first` call actually executes the query described by the `where()` relation with a limit of 1, and returns the record matched if there was any.

Comment: Would this do the same thing? FacebookProfile.find_by_facebook_id(session[:facebook_profile_id])

Comment: Yes, it should. However, those style of finders are deprecated as of Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error, `where` does not return a single object, but rather an enumerable collection of objects that suit the criteria you specified. This is why your `id` method does not exist on the object.

You could append `.first` to the end of `@facebook_profile = FacebookProfile.where(:facebook_id => session[:facebook_profile_id])` to achieve the results you want.